# In Object Orient JS, I'm trying to dynamically add an object to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

The code below is for a very simple game. I am trying to 
dynamically add a player object to an array of players.
Basically add this...
    {playerName:'Ziggy', playerId:0},
into this... 
    this.Players = [];

The code is fairly simple and self explanatory. 
The players that are hard coded in the players array is 
just there to help me troubleshoot.

```
var BobsGame = function(){
this.Players = [
   {playerName:'Ziggy', playerId:0},
   {playerName:'Mark', playerId:1}];
}

var Player = function(name, id){
    this.playerName = name;
    this.playerId = id; 
}

BobsGame.prototype.addPlayer = function(Player, id){
    this.playerName = Player;
    this.playerId = id;
    this.Players.push(this.playerName, this.playerId);
    //alert('Player ' + name + ' with an id of ' + i  + 'has been created');
}

var myGame = new BobsGame();

$('#addPlayer').click(function(){
    id = myGame.Players.length;
    name =  $('#addPlayerName').val();
    newPlayer = new Player(name, id);
    myGame.addPlayer(newPlayer, id);
    alert(JSON.stringify(myGame.Players, null, 4));
})
```

the problem is in the AddPlayer function, i guess? i have tried several diff variations on what  is above but is not working. thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `myGame.addPlayer(newPlayer, id);` just do `myGame.addPlayer(newPlayer);`

Then the addPlayer function need only be:

```
BobsGame.prototype.addPlayer = function(Player){
    this.Players.push(Player);
}
```

Then you are actually putting that object into the array, which you can use to fetch name/id whatever.

Unless of course for some reason, you do only want name and ID, in which case:

```
myGame.addPlayer(newPlayer); //No need to pass the id as well, as it's in the newPlayer object

BobsGame.prototype.addPlayer = function(Player){
    this.Players.push({name:Player.playerName,id:Player.playerId});
    // or - this.Players.push([Player.playerName,Player.playerId]);
}
```

For simplicity I would change the properties of the Player object to be `name` and `id` to simplify references. That way you can do `player.name` instead of `player.playerName`

Comment: Minor point; shouldn't 'instance' variables start with a lowercase letter? (So `Player.id` instead of your proposed `Player.ID`.)

Comment: @11684 I've never come across an issue with uppercase/sentence cased properties.. or is this an unwritten rule/coding convention?

Comment: This is a coding convention, yes. Classes: uppercase first letter, variables: lowercase first letter (every new word in an identifier starts with an uppercase letter in both cases). Note in C# this is different and some people use underscores between words in identifiers instead of starting those with an uppercase letter.

Comment: @11684 Fair enough, have updated my answer to suggest `id` instead of `ID`

Comment: var BobsGame = function(){
    this.Players = [];
    }

    var Player = function(name){
 this.playerName = name;
    }

    BobsGame.prototype.addPlayer = function(Player){
 this.Players.push({name:Player});
    }

    var myGame = new BobsGame();

    $('#addPlayer').click(function(){
 name =  $('#addPlayerName').val();
 newPlayer = new Player(name);
 myGame.addPlayer(newPlayer);
 alert(JSON.stringify(myGame.Players, null, 4));

    })

Comment: sorry, guess i can't submit code in comments. the jason stringify function is returning this:

Comment: [
    {
        "name": {
            "playerName": "undefined"
        }
    }
]

Comment: @TopTomato It works okay for me on [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SmokeyPHP/gn7sK/2/)